# Does an EditForm can be declared inside a blazor component?

Tags: forms, validation, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

My question is simple : "Does an EditForm can be declared in a blazor component or it must be declared in a blazor Page?"
I am trying to use a EditForm inside a component used in multiple pages but I have trouble with data annotations validation messages that do not show up systemically.
If I move the component code in a blazor Page, it works.

Comment: A 'page' is just a component with a routing (`@page "..."`) attribute set. So this is not the cause of your differences. Create a [mre].

Comment: as @HenkHolterman said, a **page** is a component with routing. This means, anything you can do in a component can be done on a page and vice versa. However, it is still difficult to debug. So please provide a code/picture of the problem to help you further.